# Как остановить объект, при достижении координат?

Tags: unity3d

Объект двигается в сторону нажатия мыши, но не останавливается при достижении. Я пробовал сделать условие если координаты объекта и нажатия равны, то обнулять скорость, но объект пролетает мимо и это не работает.

```
private float speed;
Vector3 dir = Vector3.zero;
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Vector2 m_pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        dir = (m_pos - (Vector2) transform.position).normalized;
    }

    transform.Translate(dir * speed);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private float speed = 10f;
private Vector2 mousePos;
private Vector2 worldPosition;
 void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        worldPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);
    } 
    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, worldPosition, speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Это может происходить потому, что ваш объект пролетает на большой скорости мимо целевой точки. Например, до цели осталось `2`, а объект двигается со скоростью `3`. Он просто на `1` перелетит цель и точного равенства не будет.

Вы не приложили код, которым вы проверяли равенство координат объекта, к тому же вы не описали, что происходит с объектом (`не останавливается` - а что? Летит дальше, выдает ошибку...), однако могу предположить, что вам следует использовать [Vector3.Distance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html). То есть

```
if (Vector3.Distance(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), transform.position) < 0.1f) // Двигаем
```

- Значение 0.1 - погрешность

Comment: О, сотый ответ :)

Comment: Да, он просто пролетает мимо

Comment: @MaxProvy Если мой ответ вам помог, вы можете принять его, нажав галочку. Если у вас остались вопросы, вам следует добавить их, ибо сейчас все выглядит как: вопрос задан, ответ дан, автор вопроса говорит о неверности ответа, следвовательно все верно, все норм. Так если все норм - примите ответ, если нет - дополните вопрос:)

Comment: ваш ответ помог, но потерпел критику, так как "До тех пор, пока скорость значительно не превысит 0.1 за кадр и объект будет бесконечно стремится в одну точку при этом дергаясь в конвульсиях."

Comment: @MaxProvy Чего-чего? В каких конвульсиях? Это цитата? Откуда? А если не цитата, то почему в кавычках? Данное мной условие поможет понять, приблизился ли объект уже объект к цели или нет. А уж как двигать - это вам решать. Например, в вопросе вы двигаете Translate, в своем же собственном ответе используете MoveTowards, а в чем ошибка моего ответа-то?